# Hibernate mapping a Map (HashMap) always add new row instead to update

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to make an Entity to support localization.

Entity -     `RoadAssistance`

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class RoadAssistance{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;



 /* Localization ....*/
 @MapKeyColumn(name = "locale")
 @MapKeyType(value = @Type(type = "java.util.Locale"))
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roadAssistance")
 Map<Locale, RoadAssistanceI18n> roadAssistanceI18n = new HashMap<>();


 /*Map Helper method for locale*/
 public RoadAssistanceI18n getRoadAssistanceI18n(Locale locale) {
    return roadAssistanceI18n.get(locale);
 }

 /// GETTERS AND SETTRE // W/O equals and hashCode implementation..

}
```

Entity - `RoadAssistanceI18n`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "road_assistance_i18n")
public class RoadAssistanceI18n{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

  private String address;

  @Lob
  private String description;

  @ManyToOne
  RoadAssistance roadAssistance;

  /// GETTERS AND SETTRE // W/O equals and hashCode implementation..
}
```

And in the view (Thymeleaf) I have the following

```
<div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 mt-3">
  <textarea data-th-field="*{roadAssistanceI18n[__${#locale}__].description}" rows="10" class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
</div>
```

[image]

For the persistence, I'm using Spring data.
Everything is working perfect and I can add/view the description in different languages and it works. The problem is that when I update the description, in the database table I get new rows for every update. I'm working with the reference from the persisted entity and override the map from there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your HTML I cannot see the part where you are sending the id of the currently edited entity. The issue is probably that you are persisting an RoadAssistanceI18n entity where the id is null which will result in a new entry inside the database. If you set the id correctly Hibernate will update the values instead of creating a new entry.

Comment: you are right. What is the proper way to handle such IDs? Where to store the ID?

Comment: Usually you would send that information in a hidden input field: <input type="hidden" data-th-field="*{roadAssistanceI18n[__${#locale}__].id}" />

Comment: OK, but If somebody change the ID with DevTools for example? I should do very checks in the backend which creates a lot of overhead?

Comment: You always have to check in the backend. This especially applies to web applications since they are easy to modify but in general you must not trust user input.